# i want the physical presence of a label go away -swift

Tags: swift, uilabel

so basically I have a label that represents and networking error. I use the hidden property of the label to make it visible whenever there is no wifi, but the problem is, even if i make the hidden property true, you can still see a blank space in the view that is where the label is supposed to be. I'd like to make the physical presence of the label disappear, not just its visibility.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove it from its parent view:

```
label.removeFromSuperview()
```

Comment: and how would I add it back in?

Comment: by simply adding it to it's parentview again: `yourParent.addSubview(label)`